# English equivalent of Polish saying "The truth is like an ass, each person has its own"

Tags: phrase-requests, idiom-requests

I'm looking for English equivalent of colloquial but popular Polish saying "*Racja jest jak dupa, każdy ma własną*" that literally means "*The truth is like an ass, each person has its own*".

**Explanation**
This saying is a quote of part of Józef Piłsudski's conversation with a journalist. I guess it's self explanatory.

Comment: Opinions are like assholes- everyone’s got one and they all stink.

Comment: @Jim you should put that as an answer.

Comment: "Like the Polish say: The truth is like an ass, each has its own."

Comment: *Beauty is in the eye of the beholder*?

Comment: "racja" is more like "right" than "truth" non?

Comment: Yes but I think it would be the same in the sense of meaning: beeing right or knowing the truth and I chose the truth because it sounds better

Comment: A ?polite or safe for work spin I've heard is, "Opinions are like armpits."  We all have them, and they make us sweat.

Answer (score 1):

***to each his own***/ (PC variant) ***to each their own***

> One has a right to one's personal preferences, as in *I'd never pick that color, but to each his own*. Versions of this maxim appeared in the late 1500s but the modern wording was first recorded in 1713.
>
> [The American Heritage® Dictionary of Idioms by Christine Ammer](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/to+each+his+own)

***(It's) different strokes for different folks***

> (*mainly American*) Something that you say which means that different people like or need different things *I've never enjoyed winter sports, but different strokes for different folks*.
>
> [Cambridge Idioms Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/different+strokes+for+different+folks)

Answer (score 1):

**[There's no accounting for taste](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/there-s-no-accounting-for-taste)** is appropriate when the context is regarding personal opinions.

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/there-s-no-accounting-for-taste)

Answer (score -1):

**Everyone sees the world his own way.**